# Associative Arrays not supported in IE 7?

Tags: javascript, object, associative-array

I have a problem retrieving data from my associative array.

To be clear, this is what my code is:

```
var modelTable = {};
```

Then I save something to the object:

```
//inside getJSON-call:
$.each(data.Models, function (index, val) {
    modelTable[val.Name] = val;
});
```

In in this case, **val** is just a json object:

```
{
    Models : [
        {
            Name: "4-stroke (EBE)",
            ModelNumber: "VRE",
            Engine: "125ccm"
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I try to fetch data from my `modelTable` like this:

```
var model = modelTable["4-stroke (EBE)"];
```

The object is null or undefined, according to IE's developer tools:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'Name': object is null or undefined
```

**Edit:** Large code-snippets:

It's basically two input fields for searching (with jQuery UI autocomplete; not important). **First** box, is used to select a motorcycle brand (make), then **second** is populated when a brand is selected and contains a name for the model. The *value (javascript `.text()`)* of the second input field is used to find all the specific data in `modelTable`, because I need those data to submit my search form.

```
$(function () {
    if ($('#mc_search').length) {
        init_mc_makes();
    }
});

var modelTable = {};

function init_mc_makes() {
    //populates the brand drop down list in jquery ui autocomplete
}

function init_mc_models() {
    //populates the model drop down list in jquery ui autocomplete
    //and iterates the json data to save associative data in modelTable
    //calls submitSearch(name, brand)
}

function submitSearch(name, brand) {
    var model = modelTable[name];
    var chosenModelNumber = model.ModelNumber; //Unable to get value of the property 'ModelNumber': object is null or undefined 
    //submits form with data...
}
```

Comment: Not enough code. Obviously `modelTable` is not in scope when you attempt to access it so you need to make it be, but without a larger snippet we can't tell you how exactly.

Comment: You mean that `data` has that JSON value right ? not `val`

Comment: @Jon `modelTable` is declared on top level scope (not in dom-ready). I will add more code then.

Comment: IE7 does not support JSON, it's available IE8+.

Answer (score 0):

If the code you're showing is executed after dom-ready, the `$()` callback will be executed *synchronously*. For example, the output of this code:

```
$(function () { console.log(1); });
console.log(2);
```

depends on whether it's executed *before* the DOM is ready (it will first output `2`, and then later – when the DOM is finally ready – `1`) or *after* it's ready (in that case, it will output `1`, then `2`).

I suspect that your code is only executed when the DOM is ready (e.g. it's in an asynchronously loaded file, or is itself wrapped in a `$()` call). Whether or not this happens may indeed depend on the browser that's used, as things like availability of the `defer` attribute on script tags or how fast the DOM is constructed can actually influence this. This is just guessing though; it's hard to tell without more context.

If this is correct, however, `init_mc_makes()` is called immediately; in particular, it's called before the assignment

```
modelTable = {}
```

is made. Due to variable hoisting, `modelTable` already exists at this point, but it is `undefined`.

If this theory is correct, moving

```
var modelTable = {};
```

*above* the `$(...)` call should fix the issue.